# How can be possible to use Reac to make dynamic websites if the production build is made entirely of statics files?

Tags: reactjs, static

If building a react app produces only static files how can dynamic websites be created with react?

Or can react build dynamic content too?

I have only made statics websites with react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes - React can provide dynamic content.. You can also configure React to be a "dynamic" site (aka server side rendered) by using something like [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/)

[Rather useful article..](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/5-reasons-static-sites-rock#toc-what-are-static-sites)

***To elaborate...***

The relationship between a dynamic site and dynamic content is not mutually exclusive. A static site can most definitely provide dynamic content..

When you boil it down, a NON-static, or dynamic, website essentially refers to a website (or certain pages within a website) that are rendered server side.  A static site refers to a website (or certain pages within a website) that are pre-built and then served to the client..

In the case of 'dynamic' websites, dynamic data is gathered server side and injected into `html` via some sort of a templating engine.. (Razor on ASP, Handlebars on Node, Jinja on Flask, to list some examples) ... As for 'static' sites, dynamic data is usually retrieved from a backend API that resides in a separate location than the web server that served the 'static' content - the requests, etc are all performed *FROM THE CLIENT SIDE*..

Basically, take the terms "dynamic site" and "static site" with a grain of salt.. Dynamic content is not mutually exclusive to either paradigm, and can exist using either paradigm.. You can have a dynamic site that doesn't have dynamic data..

Dynamic sites inject dynamic data into html server side, then send it to the client for viewing.  Static sites gather dynamic data from a server somewhere (could be an API you control, or some 3rd party API), and then inject that data into the markup - difference is *this is ALL done client side*. If you wanted to retrieve data from a third party API using a dynamic/server side rendered site, the client would request a page from your web server, then your web server would query the 3rd party API, and inject that into HTML, then send the HTML back to you..(at a high level).. With that being said - you can still call 3rd party APIs client side, manipulate data, and manipulate the DOM client side, when using server side rendering..

Static sites basically send the entire website to the client (at a high level) upon the initial request - even if it contains multiple "pages".

Answer (score 0):

React can be inter-mixed with dynamic server-side code such as PHP, ASP.Net, etc. In the case of ASP.Net, you can just use the React templates for ASP.Net, rather than using pure React-only templates such as CRA, or NEXT, or you can install React manually into your ASP.Net project.

If you want to build a React App that strictly produces static files for some reason, and still want some dynamic behaviour (e.g. loading from database), then you might want to look at **JAMStack**. The main idea is for dynamic operations, you either:

- Get the dynamic data from an API on the run-time of your static pages
- Get the dynamic data from an API on build/compile time using **Static Site Generators (SSG)**